How to read more that 10 characters in assembly?
So I wrote a program where it shows a position of numbers in a line for example if I write abc123 it prints 4 5 6. My problem is the program I have written doesn't read more than 10 characters and doesn't show the position after 9. I'm very new to assembly so I'm not exactly sure what even the problem is.
.model small

.stack 100h

.data
    buf db 255
    howMany db ?
    char db 255 dup (?)
    msgIvesti db "Iveskite eilute:", 10, 13, "$"
    msgRezult db "Rezultatai:",10,13,"$"
    count db 0

.code 
Start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, OFFSET msgIvesti
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx,OFFSET buf
    int 21h

    mov ah, 9
    mov dx,OFFSET msgRezult
    int 21h

    mov cl, howMany
    mov ch, 0 ;
    mov si, OFFSET char

cycle:
    lodsb 
    inc count
    cmp al,'0'
    jb notDigit
    cmp al, '9'
    ja notDigit
    mov dl,count
    add dl, '0'
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
notDigit:
    ;inc bx
    dec cl
    cmp cl, 0
    jne cycle

endi:
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
END Start

I need this program to be able to read more characters and print numbers positions further than it does now.

You will just need to count using more than one digit. You can keep it text based or you can count in binary and convert it for printing.

Your program will read many more than 10 characters. The trouble is in the way that you display the count. Merely adding "0" can only work for numbers smaller than 10, so occupying but a single decimal digit.
If more is needed then you'll have to convert the number into a string of characters and print that text. See Displaying numbers with DOS

mov dl,count
add dl, '0'
mov ah, 02h
int 21h


is to be replaced by (copied from the linked Q/A and modified to operate in your loop):
    mov     al, count
    mov     ah, 0
    mov     bx, 10          ;CONST
    xor     bp, bp          ;Reset counter
.a: xor     dx, dx          ;Setup for division DX:AX / BX
    div     bx              ; -> AX is Quotient, Remainder DX=[0,9]
    push    dx              ;(1) Save remainder for now
    inc     bp              ;One more digit
    test    ax, ax          ;Is quotient zero?
    jnz     .a              ;No, use as next dividend
.b: pop     dx              ;(1)
    add     dl, "0"         ;Turn into character [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
    mov     ah, 02h         ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h             ; -> AL
    dec     bp
    jnz     .b

